# Passing parameter to a action in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have added this rule in url manager

```
 'rules' => array(
          'blog/<id:\d+>' => 'blog/index',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
          '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
       )
```

and when I requested url mysite.com/blog/index/1  no error the action index of blog controller was called. But when I requested mysite.com/blog  it displayed a error page not found.But I still want it to call action index of blog controller.

Comment: I don't get it, could you provide more details?

Comment: @NishantSolanki I am new to yii2. So not able to understand url and parameter

Comment: @ankita have you tried adding `'blog' => 'blog/index'` or  `'blog' => 'blog/list'` in your url manager??

Comment: I have added 'blog' => 'blog/index'

Comment: @NishantSolanki  my .htaccess file is same as yii2 documentation

Comment: @NishantSolanki no effect of othr rules.It  works same `blog/ ` displays error and `blog/1` render the page.

Answer (score 0):

Blog/
Blog/Index
Blog/Index/1
All above requests will redirect you into the index page, because of its default behavior.

But Blog/1 will create a request for the action named "1".

Comment: this is not the answer of the question, you should put this in comment area... please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Please try below configurations for your `url manager`, try setting `'urlSuffix' => '/'` and let me know

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'cacheID' => false,
        'caseSensitive' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'urlSuffix' => '/',
        'useStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => array(
               'blog/<id:\d+>' => 'blog/index',
               '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
               '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
               '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ) 
)
```

Comment: I have solved it using `Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam()`